# How to find the table metadata from Petaho kettle transformation?

Tags: testing, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am new to pentaho Kettle. I am trying to validate the table metadata using pentaho kettle. for that currently I am trying with'metadata structure of stream' step and writing it in excel file(My Input here is my sql table input). but data types produced by kettle transformation and actual data type from MySql table are different.

Data types from Kettle using metadata structure of stream step :
actor_id|Integer , 
first_name|String , 
last_name|String , 
last_update|Date.

Data type from My Sql 
actor_id|smallint unsigned , 
first_name|varchar(45) , 
last_name|varchar(45) , 
last_update|timestamp.

is there any other way to find table metadata in kettle to use it in ETL metadata testing ? Or Any other kettle transformation step which provide table metadata like Mysql ?

Comment: The one which you have mentioned are Pentaho built-in Datatypes like String,Date,Integer. You need to write the Query in table input using DBA tables .

Comment: Yup.. will try that. Thanks.:)